# How to synchronize two thread that are not mine

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm in difficult situation in which I need to (because of the bug) synchronize two threads, but I'm not creator of those two threads (it's part of software I'm using).

There are two threads in my application working with "same" data, but each thread has it's own copy of the data. What I want to achieve is, that one thread will do nothing (I can modify executed code) when it find (somehow) that another thread did the work already (I do not want to do that work again).

I have an identifier in data, that I can use to "mark" the work as done. Where? Which object instance use for that? That's my question. I'm looking for some hints/ideas. Pure Java is preferred in worst case I can use some library.

Comment: What is your identifier? Can you use a shared Set to save all processed indentifiers?

Comment: Identifier is `String`, but I can parse `long` from it. Can you add more details about that shared Set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Set` that needs to be accessible by both threads. There, you store the IDs of each data object that has already been picked up by one of the threads. Access to the `Set` needs to be synchronized, but only for the short time of retrieving and updating the flag. The actual work on the data is done outside the synchronization.

```
Set<String> statusSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

Your thread implemenation may then look like this:

```
void run() {
    String dataId = data.getId();
    boolean workDone = true;
    synchronized (statusSet) {
        if (!statusSet.contains(dataId)) {
            workDone = false;
            statusSet.add(dataId);
        }
    }                 

    if (!workDone) {
        // ... work with the data
    }
}
```

Now, if you have two threads that both have a copy of the same data to process, one of them will enter the `synchronized (statusSet)` block first, while the other one has to wait. The first thread will find that the data has not yet been processed and will update the status set. It will leave the synchronized block and start processing the data. At the same time, the second thread can now continue and will find that the data has already been flagged as processed.

Comment: Me or you missed something - "...but each thread has it's own copy of the data...". Let me know if I misundestood something. Thanks for reply anyway ;-)

Comment: Oh.. I guess I missed that! If it is a deep copy, where every single property is its own instance, the described approach will not work here.

Comment: Data is retrieved from DB - same data, but different instances of everything (so, yes, kind of deep copy)...

Comment: I updated the approach to use a status map to track the processing of the data.

Comment: I see, probably I have to use `static` modifier for that map, because the executed code is not directly derived from `Thread`, it's kind of used in framework (I have no sources for it). I'll try and let you know ;-)

Comment: @Jack you don't need a map with boolean, a simple set will suffice, once you add the identifier to the set it is marked as done.

Comment: @ Leonard Yes, I realized that after I had typed the code example but was too lazy to rewrite it - I changed it anyway now ;)

Comment: In my code I used `Set` also and it works, my initial solution was more difficult and ugly...

Answer (score 0):

Solution is same like double checked in Singleton

In your application you have to keep one boolean in your Data Object with volatile keyword.